# how to set up test lab for windows based application

Tags: windows, architecture, operating-system, installation

I am writing an application which supports Windows OS from XP to 8.
I test the application on each flavor of Operating system before every release.

However in the real time, there are users who face issue infact running on the same configuration i tested here.

I am not sure what could go wrong between the User machine and my Test machine. Its getting hard as we move further into releases.

Now i am curious how big company who develop windows based application test their products before releasing to customers.

Is there anyone who can advice what are the check list I should be aware of for better product testing.

Appreciate your time reading this post!!!

Answer (score 1):

[SmartBear’s Automated Build Studio](http://smartbear.com/products/software-development/software-release-management/software-release-distrubuted-builds) supports WMI and Microsoft Virtual Server 2005, which makes it possible to create macros that will perform automated testing on several virtual machines having different operating system.

Hope below links would help you better:
http://support.smartbear.com/articles/abs/automated-application-testing-on-multiple-os/
and
http://smartbear.com/products/software-development/software-release-management/software-release-distrubuted-builds/virtual-software-builds